# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null while still using window.onload to delay

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am trying to write a script that changes the color of the text if it is an active screen (there are probably more efficient ways to do this). The error I am getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` My JavaScript (the entire page)

```
function main() {
    var cardDiv = '<div id ="cardScreen"><a href="cardScreen.html">';
    var card = "Card";
    var closer = "</a></div>";
    var color = (function color1(Check) {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(Check))
            return "red";
        else
            return "white";
    });
    card.fontcolor = color("cardScreen");
    var cardDivPrint = cardDiv + card + closer;
    window.onload=document.getElementById("header").innerHTML= cardDivPrint;
}
main();
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="../css/MasterSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div>Content goes here.</div>
 <script src="../scripts/essentials.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The IDE (Visual Studio 2015 Cordova) says that the error is on this line in the JavaScript `"var cardDivPrint = cardDiv + card + closer;"` I have looked at multiple similar problems and applied what was relevant (also tried changing window.onload to document.onload) but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Since you are including the script after the element, finding the element should work, even if some parts of your code are incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onload` expects function to be executed after page is completely loaded. Otherwise it'll treat it as simple assignment statement and execute. Use function as follow:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = cardDivPrint;
};
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of using `main()`, use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

    var cardDiv = '<div id ="cardScreen"><a href="cardScreen.html">';
    var card = "Card";
    var closer = "</a></div>";

    var color = window.location.href.indexOf(Check) !== -1 ? "red" : "white";

    card.fontcolor = color("cardScreen");
    var cardDivPrint = cardDiv + card + closer;
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = cardDivPrint;
});
```

Comment: `var color = (funct…` should probably be reduced to a ternary.

Comment: @royhowie Yes. Reduced

Comment: and if you're into micro-optimizations, you should use `=== -1`.

Comment: @royhowie Can you please explain `micro-optimizations` and it's techniques, if possible or give me links. By the way, Updated

Comment: I meant nominally faster to the point that it hardly matters. (although if you want a link, people seem to use `=== -1` more often than `> -1`, e.g., [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on mdn)

Answer (score 0):

**Call the main function at the end of your body content**

You are getting this error just because the element dose not exists at the time of its selection by JS DOM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
<link href="../css/MasterSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
function main() {
    var cardDiv = '<div id ="cardScreen"><a href="cardScreen.html">';
    var card = "Card";
    var closer = "</a></div>";
    var color = (function color1(Check) {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(Check))
            return "red";
        else
            return "white";
    });
    card.fontcolor = color("cardScreen");
    var cardDivPrint = cardDiv + card + closer;
    window.onload=document.getElementById("header").innerHTML= cardDivPrint;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div>Content goes here.</div>
<script>main();</script>
</body>

</html>
```