# Cannot get value of textarea with Shopify Product Options by Bold

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify

I'm trying to get the value of a textarea with Shopify [Product Options by Bold](https://apps.shopify.com/product-options) and it is currently not working. I am able to get the value of a textarea locally, but I can not get the value when I move the code over to Shopify. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057610/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827135/error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null) to no avail.

Here's the relevant code:

```
document.getElementById("248832").onkeyup=function(){getVal()};
var textbox = document.getElementsByName("properties[Message Body]")[0].value;
```

and here's the textarea I'm trying to get the value of

```
<textarea data-option-key="ta_248832" id="248832" class="bold_option_child shapp_full_width " name="properties[Message Body]"></textarea>
```

When I try to run this on Shopify, I get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeyup' of null", although I did notice that at one point shopify runs the following jQuery code, which might be what's causing my problem:

```
<script>
jQuery('#248832').change(function (){conditional_rules(7437760391);})
</script>
```

I am trying to get the value of the textarea so I can run get the amount of words in said textarea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to see if the element that is returned as `null` has loaded yet. Others in similar situations fixed this by loading the script last. Hope this is helpful :)

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25018299/1305878
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31333349/1305878
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544789/1305878

Comment: This fixed it! Just had to make the script load last and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You are trying to use something similar to jQuery methods without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("248832").onkeyup=function(){getVal()};
```

while DOM elements don't have the `onkeyup` method. It should be

```
jQuery("#248832").on("keyup",function(){getVal()});
```

**Extra notes**

even without using the recommended '.on' method, you have to write it as

```
jQuery("#248832").keyup(function(){getVal()});
```

([docs](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)), not as

```
jQuery("#248832").onkeyup(function(){getVal()});
```

If you'd like to use DOM methods, that would be

```
document.getElementById("248832").addEventListener("keyup",function(){getVal()});
```

Also, may be you have wrote this as a minimal example, but the fact that you only call `getVal()` and don't pass the value somewhere sounds strange, although I don't know if what `getVal()` does exactly.

Comment: Just tried it with jQuery and with the DOM Method to no avail. Got the following error with the DOM Method:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`